# check if dates fall in range dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to do a simple reservation system, and I would like to have an sql query to check if the dates are available and that no date in the date range is taken.

Example: there is this date taken: 2016-01-01  -> 2016-01-08
And I have to check dates like:

- 2015-12-25 - 2016-01-03
- 2015-12-25 - 2016-01-20
- 2016-01-04 - 2016-01-06
- 2016-01-04 - 2016-01-10
- 2016-01-01 - 2016-01-08

These are the scenarios I had thought of. But while researching, all the examples have 2 sets of dates to check. All the scenarios are not to check unknown dates from the database. 
I am lost. If anyone can help I would appreciate. Maybe you had used this scenario in the past.

Comment: I didnt get the problem, do u want to compare given interval with several sets or what?
And can you write more about what you have already done

Comment: You want to know if two date ranges overlap? What if the end of on period matches the start of the other period, is this overlapping? E.g. end 2016-01-10 and start 2016-01-10?

Comment: yes exactly.I will include your scenario to my list thanks. Can you help please? Is it possible to do it with SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
For future reference for anyone who has this problem, here is how I solved my issue :

$query  = "SELECT * FROM booking WHERE ";
        $query .= "checkInDate >= $chkInDate AND checkOutDate >= $chkOutDate OR ";
        $query .= "checkInDate >= $chkInDate AND checkOutDate <= $chkOutDate OR ";
        $query .= "checkInDate <= $chkInDate AND checkOutDate >= $chkOutDate OR ";
        $query .= "checkInDate <= $chkInDate AND checkOutDate <= $chkOutDate OR ";
        $query .= "checkInDate =  $chkInDate AND checkOutDate  = $chkOutDate ";
```

Comment: If this solves your problem you never had one. This is exactly the same as `WHERE 1=1`, i.e. no filter at all :-)

Answer (score 0):

Two periods (s1,e1) and (s2,e2) **overlap** when s1 <= e2 and e1 >= s2:

```
SELECT * FROM tab
WHERE checkInDate <= DATE '2016-01-03' AND checkOutDate >= DATE '2015-12-25';
```

A period (s2,e2) is **contained** in period (s1,e1) when s1 <= s2 and e1 >= e2:

```
SELECT * FROM tab
WHERE checkInDate <= DATE '2015-12-25' AND checkOutDate >= DATE '2016-01-03';
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff3cc/2)

Comment: So you mean something like this:

SELECT * 
FROM booking 
WHERE 2015-12-25 <= checkInDate 
     AND 2016-01-03 >= checkOutDate

or this:

SELECT * 
FROM booking 
WHERE checkInDate <= 2016-01-03 
     AND checkOutDate >= 2015-12-25

Because these both return zero results and I have this reservation currently:

2016-01-01 -> 2016-01-08

Comment: If `WHERE 2015-12-25 <= checkInDate AND 2016-01-03 >= checkOutDate` is your actual condition it will never work because you're not comparing to a DATE, but a number.And when I read your question again you might not want **overlapping** but **containing**, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Example that works for me and my queries.  It has always worked accurately.

```
SET @PerBeg = ’2010-01-01’;
SET @PerEnd = ’2010-01-31’;

SELECT  
    Reservation.ArrivalDate AS ArrivalDate, 
    Reservation.DepartureDate AS DepartureDate, 
. . . 

WHERE

fBoolActyInPeriod(ArrivalDate,DepartureDate,@PerBeg,@PerEnd)
```

using these functions:

```
FUNCTION fBoolActyInPeriod contains this code
RETURN IF (fBoolFirstDateEarlier(ActyEnd, PerBeg) OR fBoolFirstDateEarlier(PerEnd, ActyBeg),0, 1)

FUNCTION fBoolFirstDateEarlier contains this code
RETURN IF (DATEDIFF(first, second) < 0, 1, 0)
```